# Error When Trying to Remove Dom Node from Dom Document

Tags: javascript, dom, asp-classic

I have the following ASP (js version) code:

```
var doc = Server.CreateObject("HTMLFILE");
var doc.write(content);
// the value of content has been set elsewhere and is not of concern
var elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("br");
```

So far, so good. Here is where I run into trouble:

```
if ((elements) && (elements.length > 0))
doc.removeChild(elements[0]);
```

This last fragment of code causes my website to display a "the page cannot be displayed" message. Is there something going on behind the scenes that I am not understanding? Why can I not remove a child node? Appending a node works fine as does modifying attributes of existing nodes, but I cannot remove nodes.

Comment: Its an intriguing approach to use a HTML DOM in server side code.  However it would worry me to be using a component that expects be used in a client app in my ASP server.

Answer (score 2):

`removeChild()` should be called on the parent of the node being removed like this:

```
if (elements && elements.length > 0)
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
```

Or sometimes it's helpful to have a helper function:

```
function removeNode(node) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

And, then you could do this:

```
if (elements && elements.length > 0)
    removeNode(elements[0]);
```

Comment: +1 An entirely off-topic note would be that the `elements && ` part of the condition isn't necessary since a collection will always be returned.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick. I get my examples from w3schools, and they don't always give straight forward information.

Comment: I've blocked w3schools from my google searches because they have such lousy and incomplete information.  Use other sources.  MDN is one of the better sources.  I preface most of my searches with the MDN keyword as in [`"mdn removechild"`](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mdn+removechild) to see what they say first.

Comment: @jfriend00:  In w3schools defence I consider w3schools an excellent place for someone who is a complete novice to learn about a subject.  Its short and incomplete nature opens up the subject that often other sources fail to do.  Once a developer has absorbed enough from there they should not use it as a reference but instead got to the more complete reference works by the companies behind the technologies they are using.